# Man hired to search for 'lost movie' that causes insanity

Tags: story-identification

The movie I'm trying to remember is about a man that is hired to find a film that is believed to have had all copies destroyed.

The movie in question causes the viewer to go insane.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about it?  Small details are very helpful too.

Comment: Just a quick reminder to press the "accept" button,

Answer (score 16):

This is [John Carpenter's Cigarette Burns](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0643109/). Not actually a film, but rather an episode of "[Masters of Horror](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448190/?ref_=tt_ov_inf)", an anthology TV series.

> The bankrupted owner of the movie theater 'Vogue', Kirby Sweetman, is
>   hired by the eccentric private collector Mr. Bellinger to search and
>   find the only existing print of the legendary horror film "La Fin
>   Absolue du Monde" by Hans Backovic. This lost film is considered magic
>   and cursed, and has been presented only once to an audience at the
>   Sitges Festival, driving the people insane and causing bloodshed in
>   the theater. The director, the crew and everybody involved in its
>   production seemingly have died since. Kirby owes 200,000 dollars to
>   his father-in-law, who blames Kirby for the death of his daughter
>   Annie, and accepts the assignment to pay his debt. Bellinger shows him
>   a souvenir from the film in his basement, a chained angel that had his
>   wings torn off in the movie. Kirby travels to France to meet a contact
>   and has glimpses of his beloved Annie, initiating his journey to hell.

Comment: That is it! Thank you!

Comment: @user66816: If you click on the checkmark below the voting buttons, you can accept the answer. Please do so to improve the system. :) If you're not interested in watching it online with foreign subtitles, there have been DVD releases for the Masters of Horror series. That's how I watched "Pelts" with a copy borrowed from the library.

Comment: Foreign subtitles? I don't see any for... Oh wait.

Comment: You can watch the full show on [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/44701492)